# splitting a string('_' as delimiter)

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have following string

```
String S1="S1_T1_VIEW";
```

I want it to be split and assign to string like this:

```
String permission = "VIEW";
String component = "S1_T1";
String parent = "S1";
```

I tried using using `S1.split()`  function it didn't help much.

String can also be like this

```
String S1="S1_T1_C1_DELETE";
```

That time results should be

```
String permission = "DELETE";
String component = "S1_T1_C1";
String parent = "S1_T1";
```

Any suggestions would be helpful .

Thanks in advance

Comment: only these two types of string or more ?

Comment: What are the rules? Is `permission` always the last part? Is `component` the combination of all but the last part? Is `parent` all but the last of `component`?

Comment: @mhasan the length of string before permission may vary but its always separated with underscore and follow same convention like sting before permission is always assigned to component ana parent will string before two ending underscore .

Comment: I would be tempted to say "regular expression". The given cases can be matched trivially - will it always hold? And will you be able to understand/maintain a regular expression?

Comment: @LutzHorn yeah exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming the following:

- `permission` is the part of `S1` following the last underscore.
- `component` is the part of `S1` preceding the last underscore.
- `parent` is the part of `component` preceding *its* last underscore.

If so, try the following, perhaps? This is essentially just a literal interpretation of the above rules, splitting the string by finding the appropriate underscores.

```
int lastUnderscore = S1.lastIndexOf("_");
String permission = S1.substring(lastUnderscore + 1);
String component = S1.substring(0, lastUnderscore);
lastUnderscore = component.lastIndexof("_");
String parent = component.substring(0, lastUnderscore);
```

Answer (score 5):

We could also use a regex.

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((.+)_[^_]+)_([^_]+)$");

    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        return null;
    }

    String permission = matcher.group(3);
    String component = matcher.group(1);
    String parent = matcher.group(2);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/NhZPI2

Comment: Yep, you can do that too. It'll definitely be more flexible with regards to more complex patterns than my approach, if that ever becomes an issue.